Using ConvertTo-SecureString to encrypt an API token without throwing PSScriptAnalyzer errors?
Example
Using Invoke-RestMethod to authenticate to a REST API, the response body will contain the token in clear text.
I want to write a wrapper around this so that I can store that token in a PSCredentail object, to avoid handling the API token in plain text as much as possible.
I hit challenges with PSScriptAnalyzer(PSAvoidUsingConvertToSecureStringWithPlainText) due to the fact that I can't use Read-Host to get this value.
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod @Params
$SecureToken = $Response.access_token | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object PSCredential ($Username, $SecureToken)

In this case, the call to ConvertTo-SecureString throws the PSScriptAnalyzer error, but I see no way to do the right thing (move secret to a secure string from $Response.access_token, which is a regular string) to protect it in memory while a script/module is running.  The help doc for this error in PSScriptAnalyzer only provides an example using Read-Host, which isn't possible in the use cases for automation.
I do not want to use the Secret Management module for this use case as it feels like overkill, since I have no desire to actually store this value beyond runtime of the script/module.
The only thing I could think of is maybe using Azure KeyVault to "cache" this token and then retrieve it as needed later, but this also seems to be overkill just to avoid this analyzer error.
EDIT:, This "solution" suppresses the analyzer error, but IMO, is no less "secure" than using -AsPlainText -Force, just with more steps.
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod @Params
$TokenArray = $response.access_token.ToCharArray()
$SecureToken = New-Object securestring
foreach ($t in $token) {
   $SecureToken.AppendChar($t) | Out-Null
}
$credential = New-Object PSCredential ($Username, $SecureToken)

It helps obfuscate the realtime conversion from string to securestring, at least, but it just feels more like a workaround than a solution.

Is this a Graph token? You could use Get-AzAccessToken or just Connect-MgGraph if so.

@SantiagoSquarzon , no, it is not.  It's a non-Microsoft REST API.

Then just, unless there is a existing module to get your token as a secure string, just skip this analyzer rule.

Either way, the token is downloaded as plaintext and stored in $Response.access_token as plaintext.  Probably the best thing you can do is convert it to securestring as soon as possible whichever way you choose, and then $null out $Response followed by [System.GC]::Collect() and hope that memory address gets overwritten by something quickly afterwards.
